# why I got the error "authentication error" when running 'datastax-agent'?

Tags: datastax, opscenter

When I executing `datastax-agent` with `version 5.2.X` , but I got the following error:

```
INFO [main] 2016-01-20 11:56:34,917 Waiting for the config from OpsCenter
INFO [main] 2016-01-20 11:56:34,918 Attempting to determine Cassandra's broadcast address through JMX
INFO [main] 2016-01-20 11:56:34,919 Starting Stomp
INFO [main] 2016-01-20 11:56:34,919 Starting up agent communcation with OpsCenter.
INFO [Initialization] 2016-01-20 11:56:35,287 Using 122.21.0.131 as the cassandra broadcast address
INFO [Initialization] 2016-01-20 11:56:35,486 cassandra RPC address is  nil
INFO [Initialization] 2016-01-20 11:56:35,487 agent RPC address is  122.21.0.131
INFO [Initialization] 2016-01-20 11:56:35,487 agent RPC broadcast address is  122.21.0.131
ERROR [clojure-agent-send-off-pool-0] 2016-01-20 11:56:35,814 Can't connect to Cassandra, authentication error, please carefully check your Auth settings, retrying soon.
ERROR [clojure-agent-send-off-pool-1] 2016-01-20 11:56:35,814 Can't connect to Cassandra, authentication error, please carefully check your Auth settings, retrying soon.
ERROR [clojure-agent-send-off-pool-0] 2016-01-20 11:56:36,859 Can't connect to Cassandra, authentication error, please carefully check your Auth settings, retrying soon.
ERROR [clojure-agent-send-off-pool-1] 2016-01-20 11:56:36,859 Can't connect to Cassandra, authentication error, please carefully check your Auth settings, retrying soon.
```

But I did not find where I can put the cassandra's username and password? any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: can you include the address.yaml on agents node, and the {clusterid}.conf from the opscenterd server? Also what is the rpc_address on that nodes cassandra.yaml

Answer (score 0):

You can try to configure manually credentials in your address.yaml configuration file.

cassandra_user: 
cassandra_pass: